# How to add two difference statistics in tbl_summary?

Tags: gtsummary

I am a beginner in r and trying to create some tables using this great `gtsummary` package. My question is that is it possible to use add_difference to add two separate difference statistics at the same time (or to combine these somehow)? I am able to create a perfect table with **p-values** or effect size, but not with both. Also, is it possible to use bonferroni adjusted **p-values**?
My simple code (with t.test) looks like this:

```
table1 <- tbl_summary(df, by = gr, statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})")) %>% add_difference(test = list(all_continuous() ~ "t.test"), group = gr, conf.level = 0.95, pvalue_fun = function(x) style_pvalue(x, digits = 2)))
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the table you're after is possible in gtsummary. Use the `tbl_merge()` function to merge the tables with standardized differences and the p-values. There is an example of this below. An alternative to this is to use `add_stat()` to construct customized columns.

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #BlackLivesMatter
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.1'

# standardized difference
tbl1 <- 
  trial %>% 
  select(trt, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no",
              statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})") %>%
  add_difference(all_continuous() ~ "cohens_d")

# table with p-value and corrected p-values
tbl2 <- 
  trial %>% 
  select(trt, age, marker) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt, missing = "no") %>%
  add_p(all_continuous() ~ "t.test") %>%
  add_q(method = "bonferroni") %>%
  # hide the trt summaries, because we don't need them repeated
  modify_column_hide(all_stat_cols())
#> add_q: Adjusting p-values with
#> `stats::p.adjust(x$table_body$p.value, method = "bonferroni")`

# merge tbls together
tbl_final <- 
  tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl2)) %>%
  # remove spanning headers
  modify_spanning_header(everything() ~ NA)
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-07-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Works perfect. Just modified second part a bit: %>% modify_column_hide(columns = all_stat_cols())